# How is lambda parameter inferred?

Tags: c#, lambda

This is sample code from Microsoft, explaining how chaining tasks works:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

1.    public class Example
2.    {
3.       public static async Task Main()
4.       {
5.          // Execute the antecedent.
6.          Task<DayOfWeek> taskA = Task.Run( () => DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek );
7.         // Execute the continuation when the antecedent finishes.
8.          await taskA.ContinueWith
9.               ( antecedent => Console.WriteLine("Today is {0}.", antecedent.Result) );
10.       }
11.    }
```

On line #9 `ContinueWith` is passed a lambda expression.

My question is: how does the compiler know what `antecedent` is and where to take it from? I mean, `taskA` has a `Result` property and can be passes as an argument, but does the compiler just go around the code and when it sees the first thing that can be passed it picks it?

Comment: generics have a lot of implicit behavior.

Comment: `does the compiler just go around` No. You're calling [Task<TResult>.ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8) which accepts only `Action<Task<TResult>>` or `Func<Task<TResult>,....` lambdas. There's no need for inference here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The inference is that the type of `antecedent` is `Task<TResult>` since the parameter type to `ContinueWith` is `Action<Task<TResult>>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda parameter inference matches the parameter `antecedent` to the `Task<DayOfWeek>.ContinueWith(Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DayOfWeek>> continuationAction)` `continuationAction` parameter, and so sets the type of `antecedent` to `Task<DayOfWeek>`.

`ContinueWith` passes the completed `Task<DayOfWeek>` `taskA` as the parameter to the lambda because that is what it is defined to do: see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__0___).

Answer (score 2):

The `Task` `ContinueWith` method has specific overloads that define what kind of function it accepts as the parameter which defines the function parameters. You have a lot of options so check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) for details.

The sample uses the [`ContinueWith(Action<Task<TResult>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__0___) the most basic overload where you can see the parameter is specified in the method definition this is how the `Action` parameter type is defined. You call `ContinueWith` on a `Task<DayOfWeek>` so the `TResult` type is `DayOfWeek` and the methods signature inferred looks then like this `ContinueWith(Action<Task<DayOfWeek>>)` for this case.